# Moving Two Rectangles in Pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to make a game and encountered a problem...I can't move the rectangle of player2. The two rectangles are all from the same class

```
import pygame,sys
#........
class player(object):
    def __init__(self,determination,x1,x2):
        if determination:
            self.rect = pygame.rect.Rect([x1,0,40,5])
        elif determination == 0:
            self.rect = pygame.rect.Rect([x2,475,40,5])
    
    def draw(self,surface,color):
            pygame.draw.rect(screen,color,self.rect,1)

    def handle_keys(self,determination):
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type ==  pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_a and determination:
                    self.rect.left = self.rect.left -3
                    self.rect.right = self.rect.right - 3
                elif event.key == pygame.K_d and determination:
                    self.rect.right = self.rect.right + 3
                    self.rect.left = self.rect.left+ 3
                elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT and determination == 0:
                    self.rect.left = self.rect.left -3
                    self.rect.right = self.rect.right - 3
                elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT and determination == 0:
                    self.rect.right = self.rect.right + 3
                    self.rect.left = self.rect.left+ 3


    player1.handle_keys(1)
    player2.handle_keys(0)
    player1.draw(screen,color1)
    player2.draw(screen,color2)
    #.......
```

Comment: Is the issue solved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`pygame.event.get()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.get) get all the messages and remove them from the queue. If `pygame.event.get()` is called in multiple event loops, only one loop receives the events, but never all loops receive all events. As a result, some events appear to be missed.

Get the events once and use them in multiple loops or pass the list or events to functions and methods where they are handled:

```py
class player(object):
    # [...]

    def handle_keys(self,determination, event_list):
        for event in event_list:
            # [...]
```

```py
while True:

    event_list = pygame.event.get()

    # [...] 

    player1.handle_keys(1, event_list)
    player2.handle_keys(0, event_list)

    # [...]
```